SUM of multiple rows based on ranking
I have a db like so with thousands of job numbers and the workers on each job:



JOB_NUMBER
RANK
EMPLOYEE




1
MGR
DAVE


1
MGR
JOHN


1
JR
TJ


1
JR
FRANK


1
JR
RACHEL


1
JR
GRACE



I want to show a count of how many managers, and how many JR's there are  on each job number.



JOB_NUMBER
RANK
EMPLOYEE
RANK_COUNT




1
MGR
DAVE
2


1
MGR
JOHN
2


1
JR
TJ
4


1
JR
FRANK
4


1
JR
RACHEL
4


1
JR
GRACE
4



At the minute I am using this line as I am unsure how to count the different RANK values in one column:
SUM(CASE WHEN RANK = 'MGR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MGR_Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN RANK = 'JR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JR_Count,

This gives me a count in two separate columns but also just a single count:



JOB_NUMBER
RANK
EMPLOYEE
MGR_COUNT
JR_COUNT




1
MGR
DAVE
1
0


1
MGR
JOHN
1
0


1
JR
TJ
0
1


1
JR
FRANK
0
1


1
JR
RACHEL
0
1


1
JR
GRACE
0
1



What changes do I need to make to the code in order to present a count of MGR and JR both in one column?

COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_NUMBER,RANK) maybe?

You could use the window variant of count:
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [rank])
FROM   [mytable]

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments, if you want to perform some "aggregation" between different ranks, you could partition by a case expression. E.g.:
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE [rank]
                                      WHEN 'JR' THEN 'JR_SR'
                                      WHEN 'SR' THEN 'JR_SR'
                                      ELSE [rank]
                                      END)
FROM   [mytable]


This worked perfectly, thanks. I was unfamiliar with the window variant. If there were more rankings (e.g. MGR, SR, JR) and I wanted to count MGR, and SR+JR, how could i change this function?

@niallygee you can partition by any expression, such as a case expression in this case. See my edited answer.

Working perfectly, thanks for your help. I will need to look into window functions more :)

Should probably also have Job_Number in the PARTITION BY

With all the job_numbers in the OP having the same value, TBH, I'm not sure how this factors in. You may be right.
